# NodeJS "this" empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

Why is the "this" an empty object in NodeJS?
Where does the "module.exports" belongs to?

I thought that `"module.exports..."` could be written as `"this.module.exports..."` but it won't work.

Thank you

Comment: Works for me, what set-up are you using?

Comment: NodeJS 0.8.11 in Ubuntu 12.04. I have one "app.js" file with console.log(this); and when I run it prints {}

Comment: this.module.exports.go = function()
TypeError: Cannot read property 'exports' of undefined

Comment: What context is this line in? Is it at the module level or inside a function?

Comment: @phenomnomnominal: Are you testing in the REPL?

Comment: Hmm interesting, when I run `node` from the shell, `this.module.exports` exists, but not from within the app. Sorry, but no idea!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are in an actual module:

- `module` is a reference to the current module
- `exports` is a reference to the exported data. It gets cached away by NodeJS and delivered to other modules that `require` it
- `this` is an alternate reference to the `exports` object
- `module.exports` is an alternate reference to the `exports` object
- `this.module` is `undefined`

`this` is empty because as noted above it is a reference to the same object as `exports`, which is to be populated by the developer.

If `this.module` was a reference to `module`, then since `this` is a reference to `exports`,   it would export the `module` itself along with the other exported items. I doubt this would be desired.

---

If you are in the REPL, then `this.module` is defined.