# The variable `this` in an Arrow function is the Window object in a Browser, but why is it empty in Node?

Tags: node.js, this, arrow-functions

In the browser, `this` in classic and arrow functions expectedly returns the Windows object:

```
<script>
    function testClassic() {
        console.log(this);
    }
    const testArrow = () => {
        console.log(this);
    }
    testClassic();
    testArrow();
</script>
```

[image]

But in Node, `this` is the global object only in the classic function but `this` is empty in the arrow notation function. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of "this" in node.js modules and functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770299/meaning-of-this-in-node-js-modules-and-functions)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682514/nodejs-this-empty-object

Comment: @DaveNewton Not really because it doesn't address the difference between `this` in classic functions and arrow functions as I showed above have different values.

Comment: Yes, because `this` is late-bound in JS. The arrow function forces a binding at declaration, so it’s the module; the `function`’s `this` is bound at execution time, so will be the global object. NodeJS module-izes the file.

Comment: @Dilshan The question stackoverflow.com/questions/12682514/nodejs-this-empty-object explains why `this` in Node is empty but my question is more about the different values of `this` in these various contexts, i.e. why do classic and arrow functions both give the same value in the browser, but in Node, classic functions have the global object.

Comment: My comment explains that; the dupe goes into the details regarding "this" as it pertains to modules. AFAICT the confusion here is not knowing that when you run a file in Node that file is a module.

Comment: I think this answer your question. [The 'this' keyword behaves differently in Nodejs and browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34838985/6425710)